# How to print some javascript code on html page

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html><body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function validato()
{



 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = emailio;

}

function emalio(x,y){

function ValidateEmail(mail) 
{
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.emailAddr.value))
  {
    return (true)
  }
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
    return (false)
}
 

}

</script>

</body></html>
```

I tried to print function imalio() as it is on html page by not giving parameter. but it is not doing anything. Please somebody explain it to me.

Comment: Your JavaScript defines a couple of functions but **never calls them**. Why do you expect it to do anything?

Comment: You also have a function defined within a function, which probably won't do what you think it does.

Comment: well, I was trying to print complete function itself as an output. so if my upper level function fails in calling with  its parameters then it should print the whole containt inside it as it is as a function definition.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do here is that I am trying to print different javascript code blocks as output on html page on clicking different buttons.

Comment: @padfoot, also you named your function "emalio" but when you try to print it you used "emailio".

Answer (score 2):

Quentin is right. You have not called your function.

Add `validato()` to call your function and it will print the contents of the other function in your HTML element.

```html
<html>

<body>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function validato() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = foo;
    }

    function foo(x, y) {
      function bar(z) {
        return (false);
      }
    }

    validato();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```